# Laver Cup: Why are the doubles played without No-Ad rules

Tags: rules, tennis, scoring

At the moment the new Laver Cup take place in Prague.

Does anybody know, why the doubles are played without No-Ad rules? The champions tiebreak is played in every match including the singles, so why don't the play the standard ATP rules in the doubles?

Comment: I thought no ad scoring *was* the ATP standard for doubles currently, is it not?

Comment: Yes, it is the standard at the ATP. But at the Laver Cup they now play with ad and a Champions tiebreak for the third set.

Comment: Ah sorry I misread your question - I thought you were saying why are the doubles played with no ad rules. Opposite of what you asked. My mistake.

Answer (score 4):

Laver Cup is an exhibition tournament that is not regulated by the ATP or ITF, and therefore the organizers can decided what rules to play with.

In 2017, for the first version of this tournament, the match format according to the tournament [webpage](https://lavercup.com/how-it-works) is the following:

> Both singles and doubles will be best of three sets with ad scoring. In the event of split sets, the third set will be a 10-point match tiebreaker.

Why the organizers decided to use this specific format is up for discussion. There isn't a consensus about no-ad scoring in the circuit, as seen on this [article](https://www.nytimes.com/2016/09/07/sports/tennis/no-ad-scoring-players-go-back-and-forth.html), so maybe this was a way to show you can keep ad scoring while still making matches shorter and more predictable in length. This last part is something that does have more backing from players and organizers since it could help prevent injuries, while TV has been pushing for this for commercial/scheduling purposes. It also brings ad scoring to

Examples of trials for shorter match formats can be seen in the 2017 Hopman Cup (doubles played in [Fast4](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fast4_Tennis) format) and the 2017 Next-Gen Finals will be first to 4 games with tie break at 3 all with no-ad games ([ATP website](https://www.atpworldtour.com/en/news/rule-changes-innovation-for-next-gen-atp-finals-2017)).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I was wondering, if there is a specific reason, why the doubles are played with Ad rules, like perhaps Roger Federer wan't to change the ATP's mind to get back to the classical 3 set rule in the doubles. But I think, that wasn't the intentions of the Laver's Cup founders.

Comment: Federer is sort of the Laver cup founder... it was created by Team8 which is his agency. There is a lot of discussion regarding no-ad scoring (see this [article](https://www.nytimes.com/2016/09/07/sports/tennis/no-ad-scoring-players-go-back-and-forth.html)), though I haven't read any statement from Federer on his position about this topic.